# Cannot install tflearn in python 3

Tags: python, git, tensorflow, pip, tflearn

I have tensorflow 1.11.9 for python 3 and am trying to install tflearn.

I tried installation using:

1. "pip3 install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git"
2. "pip3 install tflearn"
3. "pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git"
4. "pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git"

Nothing seems to work. pip install is installing a tflearn version for python 2 (I have python2.7 and 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04), whereas pip3 is claiming that installation is successful, but I get an error saying

> "No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn'".

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? I would be happy to provide any further information that might be required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your tensorflow version is probably a bit low. Current one is 1.4

Comment: I figured out that I was installing tensorflow using "sudo pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL", where, tfBinaryURL identifies the proper URL of the TensorFlow Python package. Doing the tensorflow installation using "pip3 install tensorflow" and then installling tflearn using "pip3 install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git" solves my problem. 

However, I am getting another warning saying "The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1, SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations".

Can you please send me a link to tf 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was installing **tensorflow** using

> sudo pip3 install --upgrade *tfBinaryURL*,

where, *tfBinaryURL* identifies the proper URL of the TensorFlow Python package. Doing the tensorflow installation using

> pip3 install tensorflow

and then installling **tflearn** using

> pip3 install git+github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git

solves my problem.